# Unable to retrieve content-rating for each video from DailyMotion using JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, dailymotion-api

Can someone please help me to figure out how to retrieve "content-rating" of each video returned by the search from DailyMotion? I would like to know if the content is child safe or r-rated, etc... I tried looking thru the list of request fields that I can specify on the search URL when performing the search against DailyMotion website, but could not determine which field to use.

This is my request URL:

https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=allow_embed,description,duration,id,status,thumbnail_url,title,views_total&private=0&hd=1&shorter_than=20&search=' + keyword + '&page=' + pageIndex + '&limit=50';

Thanks in advance.

Max

Comment: What is the value of keyword and pageIndex? 
Can you print the entire request and paste it here?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the closest you can get to a "rating" would be the explicit filter in the API reference

https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video-explicit-field

Beyond that there is also a Genre field which you could use to classify a "rating" system on some.

https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video-genre-field

Comment: You're definitely right on the `explicit` field. You could also look at the `family_filter` global parameter that filters out explicit videos https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#global-parameters-table-family_filter
But the `genre` field is fully different (it states if a video is a comedy, drama, action video, etc) and it very often returns null as filling this field is not mandatory

Comment: Absolutely right. The genre part is a little more tenuous, I was more thinking he could filter out specific genres that may be inappropriate.

Comment: Thank you Brad and Dailymotion. Based on the api documentation, I see that this field is provided back on the global list level and not per individual video in the response. Is there a similar flag on a per video basis or do I just have to use family_** flag to restrict all explicit content? Thanks

Comment: Update. I don't believe the filter_family request parameter is working on DailyMotion API. I made the following request:  https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=allow_embed,description,duration,id,status,thumbnail_url,title,views_total&private=0&hd=1&shorter_than=20&family_filter=true.. and got back a list of videos with "explicit=true" set on the response data.

Comment: set family_filter=1 or family_filter=0 not true or false. Just noticed that in the api explorer. An example is like this https://api.dailymotion.com/video/1432?family_filter=0 . where 1432 is the video ID